# Запуск liquibase на Openshift

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, openshift

Есть веб приложение, которое нужно задеплоить на Openshift. Проект собирается gradle, в build.gradle создана задача для запуска liquibase. На локальной машине все задачи правильно отрабатывают и сервер запускается на tomcat.
При попытке запуска gradle liquibase лог выдает

```
:restservice:liquibaseUpdateUnexpected error running Liquibase:
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to
jdbc:postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT/gradletest
with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

В проекте используются такие зависимости

```
'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1004-jdbc41'
'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.2'
```

Запуск задачи `:restservice:liquibaseUpdate` происходит из action_hook deploy.

Пробовал использовать версии postgresql от 9.2 до 9.4 в сочетаниях с версиями liquibase 3.4.1 и 3.4.2. На Openshift установлен postgresql 9.2.
Так же пробовал метод из: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569302/postgresql-openshift-possibly-the-wrong-driver-for-the-given-database-url

Как это дело заставить работать?

Answer (score 1):

Понял в чем ошибка - баш почему-то не заменяет переменные.
Работает все, если в скрипте градла получать свойства для подключения к БД через `Systev.getenv('some_property')`.